# In mxGraph how can I automatically put a text label on a new graph cell?

Tags: javascript, label, cell, mxgraph

I'm starting with the mxGraph JavaScript example *dynamictoolbar.html* and adding some extra functionally to it to create my own simple tool.  I want to have a default text label on a new cell when it's created by dragging from the toolbar; ideally a different default label for each shape.

For example, if I drag the ellipse icon from the toolbar to the graph, I want a new ellipse vertex on the graph automatically displaying text "New Ellipse".

I've already enabled later editing of the default label (by double-click or F2) by setting:

```
       var vertexStyle = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultVertexStyle();
       vertexStyle[mxConstants.STYLE_NOLABEL] = false;
```

and this works fine.  But how can I get a default label when the new cell is dropped ?  I'm new to mxGraph and don't understand all the classes yet.  I've gone all the way through mxCellRenderer, mxCell, mxStyleSheet, mxShape and several others and can't find it.  If possible I'd like to avoid using CSS, customised XML etc because I don't want to add those to my already huge learning curve !  A simple text label is fine.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood the question... But in the "addVertex" function here:

```
var vertex = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
```

The first "null" is the default label... If you put tere for example "test" every shape that you will drop will have the label "test".

Comment: Thank you Marco, that works perfectly !   You have saved me many hours of going around in circles and getting nowhere.

Comment: I'm glad to know this was useful!! If you can, accept this as the solution! ;)